# Help with join query into array

Tags: sql, join

EDIT: I'm using MySQL, InnoDB.

I have some trouble with the below:

My tables are user, user_matrix, user_parts.

```
user:  
id, username

user_matrix:  
userid, partcode

user_parts:  
id, label, partcode
```

What I'm trying to do is join these into a single query, where the following data:

```
user:  
1, zenph

user_matrix:  
1, abc  
1, def  
1, ghi  

user_parts  
1, arms, abc  
2, legs, def  
3, head, ghi
```

..results in a user, with the parts as the array for each row. Is this possible? I've tried but I keep retuning a single user_parts row per user row. I need the entire related rows. The output should be:

```
1, zenph, array(  
  array(1,arms,abc),  
  array(2,legs,def),  
  array(3,head,ghi)  
)
```

Appreciate ANY help. I'm currently reading up what I can but I just can't get my head around this particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would likely necessitate using a cursor to loop through the parts and add them to an array/delimited string. We would need to know what DBMS you are using to provide any code examples.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not support the use of arrays in many instances...  which server type are you using?